# Google search results showing up a URL on its search which doesn't exist on the website

Tags: htaccess, search, seo, google-search

I am using a keyword to display a website page on google search. After entering the keyword, on the first page of google, I am redirected to a page, whose domain is exactly similar to the website whose page I want to display, but it is showing a page which doesn't even exist on the domain. Also, as similar domain with spam characteristics is also getting displayed.

To practically demonstrate this issue, do follow the below steps.

1. Go to [this google search page](https://www.google.de/)
2. Type `dolce streichquartett` and click on search.
3. The 4th/5th URL has this link `http://www.dolce-streichquartett.de/?high_ry=/casinos/de/spielautomaten-casino-bregenz.php`, which is no where on the website and looks like spam
4. The 7th/8th link you see is `http://deonlinecasino.org/doc/kostenlos-roulette-spielen-spielgeld-ausdrucken.php`, which is exactly similar to the above with the title as the keyword but a different domain.

What is this issue and why is this happening?